# Does the toponym Дно decline in Russian?

Tags: грамматика, падежи, toponyms

Я сейчас нахожусь в Дно

or

Я сейчас нахожусь в Дне ?

I am especially curious about how the natives of the city go about this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Nouns are not conjugated, they are declined.

City names in Russian are declined with the exception of some foreign names, in which case the rules are quite complicated -- see http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_90 (in Russian). So the correct version is "Я сейчас нахожусь в Дне".

In my opinion, when in doubt whether you must decline a city name or not, safer would be to say "в городе X" (vs. just "в X") and not decline the name. The reason is that it's a pretty common error for Russians not to decline city names at all if prepended with "город[-е/-а/etc]".

Comment: It seems weird that Дно gets conjugated but a foreign city like Сан-Диего that also ends in о doesn't get conjugated.  Is there anything that makes this seem  natural other than "that's how things are"?

Comment: @KCd nouns cannot be conjugated, only verbs can.

Comment: @Anixx: I used the wrong term, but I think it's evident what I intended to write. In case it isn't: it seems weird that Дно gets declined but a foreign city like Сан-Диего that also ends in о doesn't get conjugated. Is there anything that makes this seem natural other than "that's how things are"?

Comment: @KCd: *Сан-Диего* is masculine, and no native Russian masculine word can end in *-о, -ё, -е*, there is no paradigm in the language for that. Even neuter loanwords ending in *-о, -ё, -е* rarely decline in Russian. For instance, words like *пальто, метро, бюро* have long since been neuter and are integral part of the language by now, still they are not declinable.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Thanks for the explanation (and for understanding my second misuse of "conjugation" in the repeated version of my question).

Comment: @Quassinoi "Сан-Диего is masculine" My understanding of it is that it is masculine only because город is masculine. However, if it were деревня Сан-Диего or село Сан-Диего it would be feminine and neuter correspondingly but still not decline, so your gender explanation is not quite convincing.

Comment: @fedja: loanwords having features of neuter words (ending in *-о, -ё, -е*) rarely if ever decline in Russian. There is a theoretical possibility of a word to be rethought as a native Russian and become declinable (like *керно*) if it were neuter, but this is pretty much impossible if it's masculine.

Answer (score 0):

*Дно* is recognized as native word, so it should be declined. Even more – Russians will doubt for a moment before saying ***в Дне***, because *на дне* is more probable and "natural" way of saying this common word.

*Сан-Диего* and *Сан-Франциско* are recognized as foreign words, so they shouldn't be declined. Some common non-native words like *пальто*, *бюро*, *кимоно* – also.

Transitional case are native toponyms like *Домодедово*, *Шереметьево*. They used to be immutable in Soviet times (don't know why), but currently more people tend to decline them: *в Домодедове* for example.

Think of it like when Russians got some new word from other language, they don't know what to do with it – what gender to use, how to decline. After some time they may adapt it and start to decline it as usual Russian word.